# windows.location.href doesn't redirect if url location pathname is the same

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, post

I have to send data to django backend and I use a post method for that 
after I evaluate the answer to create the correct link and make HTTP GET request with different location hash.

The problem is that if the pathname of the location is the same (in my case pathname) windows.location.href won't redirect.

So to summarize the url I am in is :

http://127.0.0.1:8000/generic#aaa.json

if the new location is :

location=http://127.0.0.1:8000/bbb.json

It doesn't work.

BUT if location=http://127.0.0.1:8000/generic.html#bbb.json:
IT WORKS!

So the only difference is the location pathname (generic and generic.html)

My code:

jquery request:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url:'generic',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {graph_name: 'udgram'},
                    success:function(response){   
                    new_location='/generic#'+response; 
                    document.location=new_location;  
                   window.location.reload()
})
```

Views.py post handler:
...

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    string='agocs_Medipix 1-2.
    return HttpResponse(string)
```

The javascript object location compoments( according to google developer tools is):

- ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList
- assign: ()
- hash: "#user_def_agocs.json"
- host: "127.0.0.1:8000"
- hostname: "127.0.0.1"
- href: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/generic#user_def_agocs.json"
- origin: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
- pathname: "/generic"
- port: "8000"
- protocol: "http:"
- reload: reload()
- replace: ()
- search: ""
- toString: toString()
- valueOf: valueOf()

I want to ask if there is a way to make a force redirect work for different has and if the problem I detected is correct to get proposals.

PS window.location.reload() is not convenient because that way the back forward browser doesn't work as expected

Comment: have you check console for any `JS/Jquery` errors.

Comment: There are no erros, the funcitonality is normal but I can only navigate if the location pathname is different or if i reload